# What is the value of JWT Issuer verification?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token, verification

Given a signed JWT, provided i can successfully obtain an associated public key to verify the signature, what is the value of the issuer verification?

It is my understanding that if the token had been issued by a different server, i would have been unable to verify the token with the expected public key. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You may receive/accept JWTs from a variety of sources. In that case the Issuer tells you which public key you'd use to verify a particular token.

Comment: So, you mean the issuer is just an identifier and not used in the token validation process?